# How to access view folder in laravel and check there is any blade file have or not

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-view-component

I have two folder in view file. like:

```
template1
template2
```

I want to see all the file list from specific folder. and check there is any specific blade file have or not. So i dont know how to do this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list all views, you could use the `File` facade to get an array of all the files included in your views folder. This will not show vendor views unless they have been published.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$views = collect(File::allFiles(resource_path('views')))
    ->map->getPathName()
    // ->filter(fn ($pathName) => ... ) // additional filtering
    ;
```

If you want to check if a specific view exists or not, the `View` facade has an `exists` method.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

View::exists('template1.some-view'); // returns true if template1/some-view.blade.php exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem from here.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#determining-if-a-view-exists